# How to print all values of tuple in Scala?

Tags: scala, tuples

Im learning Scala now, im trying to pass a tuple to a function that prints all elements with for loop. This is what ive done so far but obviously something went wrong.

```
object Tuple_demo {
    def main(args: Array[String])
    {
      var tup1=(10,"test",6.8)
      printMe(tup1)
    }
    def printMe(tup1:Tuple1)
    {
      for (ob<-tup1)
      {
        println(ob)
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All Scala Tuples extend [Product](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html). You can use its `productIterator` to iterate over tuple items:

```
scala> (10,"test",6.8).productIterator.foreach(println)
10
test
6.8
```

---

The type declaration of your `printMe` function is incorrect. It should be a 3-ary tuple with types of its items specified, i.e. `tup1: Tuple3[Int, String, Double]`. Also, Scala has a sugar for tuple type declarations, so the following would also be correct: `tup1: (Int, String, Double)`.

Comment: thanks! thats what i wanted! just another thing, how can i pass a tuple to another function that will handle the printing?

Comment: @AlexTal just set `Product` as an incoming type: `def printMe(p: Product) = { ... }`

Comment: @AlexTal Please see the update to my answer. Although the recommended by om-nom-nom type definition would be better since its more generic and will let your function work on any tuples.

Comment: Thank you all for the elaborated answers, that was extremely useful.